# Определение подключения пользователя к сайту на IIS

Tags: c#, iis-7

IIS (7 версия) работает как обратный прокси и при подключении перенаправляет на другой сайт.
Необходимо, чтобы после каждого нового подключения пользователя менялся адрес перенаправления, т.е. при подключении пользователя1 он отправляется на site1, при подключении пользователя2 он уже отправится на site2 и т.д.
Т.к. ссылка, в которой указывается сайт перенаправления, хранится в файле webconfig изменить ее не сложно, меня интересует, как определить, что к сайту подключился очередной пользователь?
Приложение пишу на C#.

Comment: А по каким правилам сопоставляются "пользователь - сайт"? Есть какая-либо зависимость?

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya зависимостей нет, просто счетчик - пользователь подключился к site1, ссылка перенаправления меняется на site2 и т.д.

Comment: Чем перенаправляете? URL Rewriter?

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya Да

Comment: Вам нужно, чтобы при обращении по определенному адресу URL Rewriter перенаправлял пользователя на разные адреса? Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya да, нужно чтобы  каждое, например, второе обращение переадресовывалось на site2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему используя [ARR](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) - создал веб-ферму и с помощью балансировщика нагрузки пользователи поочередно разлетаются на сервера.